# How to do inclusive range in Low Search?

Tags: low-search

I have this field

```
{!-- Age Range --}
<fieldset>
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="range-from:age"/> to <input type="text" name="range-to:age"/>
</fieldset>
```

In Low Search, when I do a range search, it seems to be exclusive. Meaning, if I search for 25 to 35, search results do not include 25 and 35 (but will return 26 to 34). How to make this inclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Low Search Range filters already are inclusive. If you're not getting the expected results, check if the field you're targeting is a valid numeric field: it should be a **Text Input** with **Content Type** set to **Number**, **Integer** or **Decimal**.